# Match the last word and delete the entire line

Tags: python, line

Input.txt File

```
12626232 : Bookmarks 
1321121:
126262
```

Here 126262:  can be anything text or digit, so basically will search for last word is : (colon) and delete the entire line

Output.txt File

```
12626232 : Bookmarks
```

My Code:

```
def function_example():
    fn = 'input.txt'
    f = open(fn)
    output = []
    for line in f:
        if not ":" in line:
            output.append(line)
    f.close()
    f = open(fn, 'w')
    f.writelines(output)
    f.close()
```

Problem: When I match with : it remove the entire line, but I just want to check if it is exist in the end of line and if it is end of the line then only remove the entire line.
Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

I saw as following but not sure how to use it in here

```
a = "abc here we go:"
print a[:-1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe with this you should be able to achieve what you want.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip().endswith(':'):
            print line
```

Here `fname` is the variable pointing to the file location.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there with your function. You were checking if `:` appears anywhere in the line, when you need to check if the line ends with it:

```
def function_example():
    fn = 'input.txt'
    f = open(fn)
    output = []
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip().endswith(":"):  # This is what you were missing
            output.append(line)
    f.close()
    f = open(fn, 'w')
    f.writelines(output)
    f.close()
```

You could have also done `if not line.strip()[:-1] == ':':`, but [`endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) is better suited for your use case.

Here is a compact way to do what you are doing above:

```
def function_example(infile, outfile, limiter=':'):
    ''' Filters all lines in :infile: that end in :limiter:
        and writes the remaining lines to :outfile: '''

    with open(infile) as in, open(outfile,'w') as out:
       for line in in:
         if not line.strip().endswith(limiter):
              out.write(line)
```

The [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) creates a context and automatically closes files when the block ends.

Comment: @Buhan Khalid, Thanks for nice solution. How about if I want to remove the line end with only digit (last line of the input file). Do I have to use regular expression ? or is there any built in function?

Comment: If your want to remove a line whose last character is a digit, then add this `line.strip()[:-1].isdigit()` to the `if` as well.

Answer (score 0):

To search if the last letter is : Do following

```
if line.strip().endswith(':'):
    ...Do Something...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expressio](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)n

```
import re

#Something end with ':'
regex = re.compile('.(:+)')
new_lines = []
file_name = "path_to_file"

with open(file_name) as _file:
    lines = _file.readlines()
    new_lines = [line for line in lines if regex.search(line.strip())]

with open(file_name, "w") as _file:
    _file.writelines(new_lines)
```